# Sublime Plugin: Share object between TextCommand and EventListener?

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to write a Sublime Plugin which consists of a `TextCommand` and an `on_modified` `EventListener`. When the command is run, it needs to create a new instance of an object which is associated with the `view` that the `TextCommand` was run in. Whenever the `on_modifed` is called in the `EventListener`, it needs to use the instance of that class that was produced when the command was last run in the view.

Here's what I tried:

```
from code import InteractiveConsole

class LivePythonCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        if hasattr(self.view, 'livePythonInterpreter'):
            print('Already had an interpreter, but replacing it.')
        else:
            print("Didn't have an interpreter, making one now.")
        self.view.livePythonInterpreter = InteractiveConsole()

class LivePythonListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified(self, view):
        if hasattr(self.view, 'livePythonInterpreter'):
            print('Modified and interpreting.')
        else:
            print('Modified but not interpreting.')
```

The first time I run the command, I get this message:

```
Didn't have an interpreter, making one now.
```

If I modify the buffer, it tells me:

```
Modified but not interpreting.
```

I run the command again and it says:

```
Already had an interpreter, but replacing it.
```

I modify the buffer again, and it tells me:

```
Modified but not interpreting.
```

So `LivePythonCommand` is able to see the interpreter that it assigns to the view from `run` to `run`. And `LivePythonListener` is listening, but it never sees the `livePythonInterpreter` that was assigned to view in `LivePythonCommand`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround... I'm not sure I like this solution or not, but here it is:

```
from code import InteractiveConsole

livePythonInterpreters= {}

class LivePythonCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        ic = InteractiveConsole()
        global livePythonInterpreters
        livePythonInterpreters[self.view.buffer_id()] = ic

class LivePythonListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_modified(self, view):
        ic = livePythonInterpreters[view.buffer_id()]
```

I think it's pretty obvious how this works... I just don't like it on account of needing a global variable. I'd love it if anyone else has a solution that works without a global variable.